# javascript string method lastIndexOf()

Tags: javascript, string, methods

I've been checking the lastIndexOf() method. Can someone explain the fourth case? The result is a bit strange, it shouldn't be -1 right?

```js
let study = "javascript";
console.log(study.length); // 10
// search chr only
console.log(study.lastIndexOf('t')); // 9; 't' is found at index 9
console.log(study.lastIndexOf('v')); // 2; 'v' is found at index 2
console.log(study.lastIndexOf()); // -1; [empty] is not found
console.log(study.lastIndexOf("")); // 10; [nothing] is found at index 10, strange result
console.log(study.lastIndexOf(" ")); // -1; space is not found
```

Comment: What should be the result in your opinion?

Comment: Same reason why `split("")` works. Nothing is found after every character, so naturally the last index it can be found is after the 10th character, index 10.

Comment: thank you. I have search a similar question first. Sorry.